# Apollo-Client + Express-Graphql Backend - Session does not persist?

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, apollo, apollo-client

I think I must be not getting something. I am trying to connect my apollo-client `localhost:8000` to my backend `localhost:4000`, with client & server on different domains. I am using apollo (`apollo-boost`) on the frontend, and `express-graphql` on the backend (**not (!) apollo-server**).

When I send some login data from the client to the server, I get back a response: a user object, or errors etc. So that's great. However, the user is never actually logged in on the server (when I check in graphiql and request the user object, it's always null).

I don't know if this is a CORS issue, since things used to work when I had both client & server on the same domain?

Here is the client side code:

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost"
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch"
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http"
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory"

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const link = new HttpLink({
  // uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  credentials: "include",
})


export const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  fetch,
  link,
  dataIdFromObject: o => o.id,
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
})
```

The relevant bits on the server are:

```
app.use(
  session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'whatever',
    cookie: {
      secure: false
    },
    store: new MongoStore({
      url: MONGO_URI,
      autoReconnect: true
    })
  })
);

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8000',
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Instruct Express to pass on any request made to the '/graphql' route
// to the GraphQL instance.
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  expressGraphQL({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);
```

Comment: "I don't know if this is a CORS issue" — Do you get an error message in the browser console which mentions CORS?

Comment: no. does this mean CORS is fine then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like their API has changed slightly. 
I fixed it by doing this on the client side:

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost"
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch"
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory"

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  fetch,
  link,
  credentials: "include",
  dataIdFromObject: o => o.id,
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
})
```

So I included `credentials: "include",` right into the Apollo Client, not in the httpLink - actually removed that one.